# Private members accessible through polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, private-members

Main Problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class p{
// virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}// try this in public and private
  public:
  virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}
  void foobar(){cout<<"pfoo"<<endl;foo();}//try with and without this
};

class d : public p{
  private:
  void foo(){cout<<"derived"<<endl;}
  public: 
  void foobar(){cout<<"dfoo"<<endl;foo();}
};

int main()
{
 //d *t = new d();
 p *t = new d();
 //t->foobar();
 t->foo();//try this and foobar()
 return 0;
}
```

Case 1: `foo()` is public in `p` and no `foobar()` in `p` and `t->foo()`

a) with `d *t`, error as `foo()` is private

b) with `p *t`, output: derived (parent object does not realize access specifier in child class)

Case 2: same as 1 but with `t->foobar()`

a) derived

b) error, parent object cant look outside `p` and `p` has no `foobar()`

Case 3: `foo()` and `foobar()` public in `p` and `t->foobar()`

a) derived

b) output: derived (`foo()` is called from `p::foobar()` but still vtable of `d` is looked up and hence `d::foo()` is called)

Case 4: `foo()` is private in `p` and no `foobar()` in `p` and `t->foo()`

a) error (`d::foo()` is private)

b) error (`p::foo()` is private)

***Specific question about Case 1 and Case 3 Below...***

Case 1 code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class p{
// virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}// try this in public and private
  public:
  virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}
  //void foobar(){cout<<"pfoo"<<endl;foo();}//try with and without this
};

class d : public p{
  private:
  void foo(){cout<<"derived"<<endl;}
  public: 
  void foobar(){cout<<"dfoo"<<endl;foo();}
};

int main()
{
 //d *t = new d();
 p *t = new d();
 //t->foobar();
 t->foo();//try this and foobar()
 return 0;
}
```

Case 1: `foo()` is public in `p` and no `foobar()` in `p` and `t->foo()`

a) with `d *t`, error as `foo()` is private

b) with `p *t`, output: derived (parent object does not realize access specifier in child class)

Case 3 code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class p{
// virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}// try this in public and private
  public:
  virtual void foo(){cout<<"parent"<<endl;}
  void foobar(){cout<<"pfoo"<<endl;foo();}//try with and without this
};

class d : public p{
  private:
  void foo(){cout<<"derived"<<endl;}
  public: 
  void foobar(){cout<<"dfoo"<<endl;foo();}
};

int main()
{
 //d *t = new d();
 p *t = new d();
 t->foobar();
 //t->foo();//try this and foobar()
 return 0;
}
```

Case 3: `foo()` and `foobar()` public in `p` and `t->foobar()`

a) derived

b) output: derived (`foo()` is called from `p::foobar()` but still vtable of `d` is looked up and hence `d::foo()` is called)

I want to know if the explanations for case 1 and 3 are correct or not.

Comment: Provide code for all cases separately.

Comment: Note that C++'s access levels are intended to make it harder to have accidents. They are not an iron-clad wall.

Comment: The compiler only needs to know the function exists in the derived class. If it's there, it doesn't check any further, so if a virtual function is `pubic` in the base, it can get accessed through the base no matter what access specifier is used in the derived class. See the discussion here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#In_detail

Comment: @user4581301 what about case 3 then?

Comment: I run case 3 and get exactly the behaviour I expect. The derived `foo` is called.

Comment: @user4581301, yeah with the p *t = new d(), I am also getting the same results, but why is the d::foo() getting called from p::foobar() , and not the p::foo() ??

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Because that's what `virtual` means. If you want `p::foobar` to always call `foo` from `p` then write the call as `p::foo();`.

Comment: `p::foo` has been hidden by `d::foo`. If you want to call `p::foo` you need to do it explicitly. Yeah. What he ^ said.

Comment: @dxiv, I have an idea about why d::foo() is getting called from p::foobar(), but I’m not absolutely sure. That’s why I am just checking with you people if the vtable is looked up when foo() is called from p::foobar()

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly It would help to think less of vtables and more about the C++ definition of `virtual`. Calling member function `foo` from `foobar` is done via the `this` pointer, so `foo();` is equivalent to `this->foo();`, and `foo` being virtual means that the call is resolved to the most derived type of the actual object. If you really want to override that you have the option to fully qualify it as `p::foo();`.

Answer (score 0):

Access qualifiers are checked statically based on the static type of an object.  The object's dynamic type has no bearing on access qualifiers.  Since the static type of `*p` is `p` and `p` contains a public function `foo`, the call is fine.  That dynamic dispatch will end up calling `d::foo` is irrelevant; only the access qualifier of `p::foo` matters.